# For $\int f < \infty$, the measure of the set of points where $f=\infty$ is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I fear this question was already discussed here, but I was not able to find it.  Please remove if it is a duplicate.

Prove: For a function $f\geq 0$, if $\int f < \infty$, then the measure of $\{x:f(x) = \infty\}$ is $0$.

Please tell me how I can improve my attempt:

By the definition of an integral, $\int f = \sup\{ \int g, g \text{ is an integrable simple function}, 0 \leq g \leq f\}$.  Because $\int f < \infty$, there exists an ISF $g = a_1 1_{A_1} + ... + a_n 1_{A_n}$, such that $\int f - \int g < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon >0$. By the definition of an integral of an ISF, $\int g = a_1 m(A_1) + ... + a_n m(A_n)$.

There must be an $A_k \subset \{x:f(x) = \infty \}$, and a corresponding $a_k$ that can be chosen to be arbitrarily large.  As such, if $m(A_k) > 0$, then $\int g$ can be arbitrarily large.  However, we have $\int g \leq \int f < \infty$, so $m(A_k)$ must equal 0.

Comment: @OveAhlman: In measure theory it is usually allowed for functions to take values from the affinely-extended real line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A_n=\{f>n\}$. Then $\bigcap A_n=\{f=\infty\}$ and $$\int n1_{A_n} =n\mu(A_n)<\int f$$

Comment: So essentially, as $n$ gets arbitrarily large, then $\mu(A_n)$ must approach zero so that $n \mu(A_n) < \int f$.  Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: @user310374 Correct.

Comment: Your proof is much more elegant than mine, but could you tell me if my proof has an error in it?  Or is there some way to make it correct?

Comment: @user310374 : ISF is a function which takes a finite number of values ? and $A_k \subset \{x | f(x) = \infty\}$ ?? this doesn't make sense, you have to consider as Pedro did $\{x | f(x) > M\}$ and let $M \to \infty$

Comment: @user1952009 [Integrable Simple Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function).  I will update the question, as you are right, that acronym is not universal.

Comment: @user310374 : "the set $\{x | f(x) = \infty\}$ has zero measure" is a joke meaning $\lim_{M \to \infty} M \mu\left(\{x | f(x) > M\}\right) = 0$ (a joke which becomes serious only when the limit is not $0$)

Comment: @user1952009 No, it is not a joke.

Answer (score 4):

$\int f=\int_{\{f=\infty\}}f+\int_{\{f<\infty\}}f$

If $m(\{f=\infty\})\neq 0$, $\int_{\{f=\infty\}}f=\infty\times m(\{f=\infty\}=\infty$.
As $\int_{\{f<\infty\}}f\geq 0$, this contradicts the fact that $\int f<\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E_\lambda=\left\{x:f(x)\ge\lambda\right\}$. Note that $\left|E_\lambda\right|$ is a decreasing function and that
$$
\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge\lambda\left|E_\lambda\right|
$$
Now if $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty}\left|E_\lambda\right|=m\gt0$, then $\left|E_\lambda\right|\ge m$ for all $\lambda$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\lambda m\\
&=\infty
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, by contradiction, we must have
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left|E_\lambda\right|=0
$$

Comment: So by $|E_\lambda|$ you mean the measure of $E_\lambda$.  Also, you have this $\int f(x) \geq \lambda |E_\lambda|$ because $\int f$ is defined as the sup of all ISF less than $f$, and $\lambda 1_{E_\lambda}$ is such an ISF, correct?

Comment: Yes on both accounts.